# Why there is a hardware limit with minimum CPU speed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu, cpu-architecture

I want to limit the CPU speed to save power. but there is a 933MHz hardware minimum CPU speed limit.
Using `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS`, and `cpufreq-set` command.

First Question is, Why there is a limit? Is it related to `Clock chip`?

Second is, Is it possible to force CPU to work at lower speeds? If yes, Is it bad for hardware?

Comment: I have no idea of the true reason. Just mentioning that dynamic RAMs require a minimum refresh rate. And you are not on the right site.

Comment: Nice philosophical question. I guess hardware is designed to work in a range of frequencies. It is not worth it (or would be very expensive) to make it work for infinitely low frequencies or outside a range. To start, maintaining volatile memory/registers would require a minimum frequency I guess. Also there are other mechanisms for saving power than lowering the frequency. If you are worried about the power consumption you can buy a power meter, I bet the power adapter or a transformer consumes more energy than an idle CPU in power saving mode. Maybe the same can be said about GPUs.

Comment: @alfC Thanks, the point is I need the battery to last as long as possible. so turning off wifi, lowering screen brightness, keeping device in cool place so the fan runs on slow rate's and so on.. but I was curios that why there is such limit.

Answer (score 2):

There might be some dynamic logic in Intel/AMD (which would only work at some minimum clock frequency since it depends on reading a result before some other input ripples through some gates and changes that output.)

Other than that, yeah, **race-to-sleep** works better than clocking really slow.  When the CPU has to wake up for something, it's better to get through that work not *too* slowly so the whole CPU core can go back into a sleep state.  That cuts not only the clock (effectively 0Hz) but also the voltage, saving much more power than any possible still-on state.

Total energy for a fixed amount of computation work decreases quickly as you back away from max turbo frequency/voltage, but it doesn't keep improving much as you get a lot slower.  Leakage current is significant, and constant regardless of clock frequency, so clocking slower (and thus making the same amount of work take longer) means you're paying for that leakage current longer.

When Skylake was released, there was a talk about CPU power management at IDF2015, going into some of these issues.  The sweet spot for power efficiency in terms of work per unit of energy is around 800 or 900 MHz.  Some Skylake CPUs (like Y series IIRC?) have HW support for cycling between sleep/idle with some duty cycle to hit a lower power & performance point than they could usefully hit by just lowering the clock speed.

wikichip has the PDF of slides, but unfortunately the audio from the talk doesn't seem to be online anywhere:
https://en.wikichip.org/w/images/8/83/Intel_Architecture%2C_Code_Name_Skylake_Deep_Dive-_A_New_Architecture_to_Manage_Power_Performance_and_Energy_Efficiency.pdf